# Removing User Defined chain having links

Tags: iptables, java, fedora, rules

I have a user defined chain which is linked with the INPUT chain in the filter table. How do i remove this link so that i can remove my user chain ? Linked in the sense i have made a jump connection from INPUT chain to the user defined chain.

I know that i can save to a file and remove the jump rule from the file but i want to do it through the terminal it self without having to save to a separate file.

Is there a way to do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `--line-numbers` option to get a listing of the relevant table with erm line numbers.

```
$ sudo iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers -vn
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1       46  3716 TEST       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
...
```

Once you know the line number of the rule you can delete it with the `-D` option

```
$ sudo iptables -D INPUT 1
```

Will delete the first rule in the INPUT table.